Trying to deploy Django API to Azure Web app
Currently trying to deploy my Django backend on to Azure. The project runs locally no problem. It also builds and deploys fine on Azure but when I visit the default domain I get a 404 not found. At first I though the issue to be around the settings module as I have 2 depending on local or if its run on Azure like is shown in this Azure tutorial with the code here in the settings.py and production.py files but it seems to be working. I have tried different setups in the production.py and including adding all the modules there but it has no effect. The logs on Azure don't return any errors only a 404 error when I try to access the site. Could the issue have something to do with how I set up the URLS? The api Url look like this
from django.urls import path
# from .views import *
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("posts/", views.PostsListCreate.as_view(), name="post-view-create"),
    path("replies/", views.RepliesListCreate.as_view(), name="reply-view-create")
]

While the project urls look like this below
from django.urls import path, include 
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("api.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Here are my views as well
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Posts
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Replies
from .serializers import RepliesSerializer

class PostsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    
class RepliesListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Replies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RepliesSerializer

I tried several different settings module setups and adding all urls onto 1. I am expecting the proper views to show up when I go to certain endpoints of the default domain on Azure.

Update to this. I ran the python manage.py collectstatic function and now I am able to access the /admin page but all other endpoints return a 500 error

If Possible, Share your github repo?

I created a Django application based on the code snippets you've provided,you can check my sample code.
I got the same 404 error, which mainly occurs when the ALLOWED_HOSTS configuration in settings.py is incorrect.
I changed ALLOWED_HOSTS to '*', allowing all domains.
This is my project/settings.py:
import os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'your-secret-key'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'yourproject.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'yourproject.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


Ensure your wsgi.py correctly sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'yourproject.settings'.

wsgi .py:
import  os 
from  django.core.wsgi  import  get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourproject.settings')
application  =  get_wsgi_application()

api/urls.py:
from  django.urls  import  path
from . import  views
urlpatterns  = [
path("posts/", views.PostsListCreate.as_view(), name="post-view-create"),
path("replies/", views.RepliesListCreate.as_view(), name="reply-view-create")
]

api/views.py:
from  django.http  import  HttpResponse
from  rest_framework  import  generics
from .models  import  Posts, Replies
from .serializers  import  PostSerializer, RepliesSerializer
class  PostsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset  =  Posts.objects.all()
serializer_class  =  PostSerializer
class  RepliesListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset  =  Replies.objects.all()
serializer_class  =  RepliesSerializer
def  index(request):
return  HttpResponse("Welcome to the Django API. Use /api/posts/ or /api/replies/ to access the API endpoints.")

I've added models.py and serializers.py to api.
api/models.py:
from  django.db  import  models
class  Posts(models.Model):
title  =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
content  =  models.TextField()
def  __str__(self):
return  self.title
class  Replies(models.Model):
post  =  models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content  =  models.TextField()
def  __str__(self):
return  self.content

api/serializers.py
from  rest_framework  import  serializers
from .models  import  Posts, Replies
class  PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class  Meta:
model  =  Posts
fields  =  '__all__'
class  RepliesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class  Meta:
model  =  Replies
fields  =  '__all__'

project/urls.py:
from  django.contrib  import  admin
from  django.urls  import  path, include
from  api  import  views 
urlpatterns  = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('api/', include('api.urls')), 
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

project/manage.py:
import  os
import  sys
def  main():
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourproject.settings')
try:
from  django.core.management  import  execute_from_command_line
except  ImportError  as  exc:
raise  ImportError(
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed"
) from  exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
if  __name__  ==  '__main__':
main()

This is my requirements.txt file:
Django==3.2.4
djangorestframework==3.12.4
whitenoise

Run the commands below to collect static files for production.
python manage.py collecstatic
python manage.py migrate


Ensure you set DEBUG = False in settings.py before deploying the web app to Azure App Service.
Make sure your Django project's virtual environment is set up correctly and active when you deploy.

Local output:


Here's the output after deployment:


